# Type Promotion in C, Passing a long as an Argument

Tags: c, c89

My understanding of type promotion of function arguments in C, is that, if I call a non prototyped function with an argument of type `char` or `short`, it will get promoted to an `int`.
**Question**: What if I call it with a `long` as argument, and `sizeof(long) > sizeof(int)`?

If the parameter is passed as a `long`, why not choosing `long` as the type to which all the integral parameters should be promoted to? isn't the reason behind type promotion of arguments, is to make compilers simpler to write, by making the parameters pushed on the stack all the same length, so that the runtime system needs only to know the number of parameters, and not to bother with their sizes?

Comment: " if I call a non prototyped function" Don't. That is not what type promotion is or is for. In that case, compiler has to guess and cannot guess any better than "probably int" for any parameter you give. Type promotion on the other hand is used when processing operation (e.g. "+", "-", ....) on more than one operand of known but different types, where one is "smaller" than the other. The smaller one gets promoted to the other ones type. If you call a prototyped function (with a known parameter type) then you can get type promotion, if the parameter is of "smaller" type.

Comment: @Yunnosch "cannot guess any better than "probably int"", actually it can guess "double" in case of float.

Comment: " isn't the reason behind type promotion of arguments, is to make compilers simpler to write" --> promotions are to bring narrow types up to the "native" (more or less) integer type for the processor for leaner/faster code.

Comment: @chux not in the case of parameter passing I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why not choosing `long`...

Because `long` didn't exist when the "promote everything to `int`" design was created.

Now, changing the default promotion rules will break just about every bit of extant C code as it would also change the behavior of calls such as `printf()` and `open()`.

Any varargs-type function would be impacted - which includes `open()`.  There are probably other, more subtle issues, but "breaking just about everything" is sufficient reason to not do it.